# How to disable WebBrowser component from loading images?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

Just loading html without images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TEmbeddedWB](https://github.com/7even11/Delphi-EmbeddedWB) instead of TWebBrowser, and you can do that easily by [change the DLCTL_DLIMAGES option to false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753277(v=vs.85))

Comment: isn't it possible with TWebBrowser? I'm not using TEmbeddedWB.

Answer (score 1):

Goto:

> Tools > Internet options > Advanced
>   Tab > Under Multimedia untick Show
>   Pictures

Answer (score 0):

One way is to edit the HTML to remove the  tags.

Comment: your suggestion is only possible with your own html files, not with a website. I think he means from websites.

Comment: @Cesar - you can get the HTML text, edit it to remove the tags, save to a file, then call  
   webbrowser1.navigate(TempFileName, flags, flags, flags, flags);

It's pretty ugly though, but it will work.

Comment: Given that the web browser control can be set not to load images attempting to change the source html is just a lame workaround, not a good programming technique. Moreover when set so the brwoser will show images placeholders - removing or disabling the tags will change the whole page layout.

Comment: @lsandon - agreed, it's not a great approach. I just tossed it out as a possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here MSDN explains how to customize the web browser control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041(VS.85).aspx

If you're using Delphi, as Nasman said, TEmbeddedWB is a much more and updated wrapper of the web browser control.